# How can I handle an alert/popup that has two text inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate my login process to my home router and I want to enter the username and the password into an alert message, unfortunately, I can't do it

after doing some research I found that I can accept the alert using

`alert = driver.switch_to.alert alert.accept()`

and sending keys into the web using a method called send_keys()

but the problem that I have two textboxes instead of one

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1")

#note I have both textboxes in the same alert
#and the alert popup once I request the page

alert = driver.switch_to.alert

alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar issue too.
driver.get("http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1") should actually login to the url as you have already mentioned admin:admin as userid and password in the url. The pop-up what I believe you get is not part of the browser but from the underlying OS. Hence cannot interact with it using selenium. Thus userid and password are passed to the url by default for login.
You need not further interact with the auth window as its handled in the url itself.
I referred to http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/

Were you able to inspect the 2 text boxes of the pop-up? If no, then they are from the underlying OS and not from browser.

Comment: this wont useful with headless mode
but good to know about it thanks (also there is python module called pyautogui no need for autoit)